# Nullable scalar types and LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, livebindings, spring4d

I want to bind a TObjectList of custom delphi objects to a grid using live bindings.  I wish to have Nullable support for the object properties so that if they do not have a value, they show up blank in the grid and edits similar to how datasets work with nullable db columns.

I'm assuiming the Delphi language doesn't have support for nullable types?

```
TMyObject = class
private
    FQuanitity: Nullable<Integer>;
    FDescription: Nullable<string>;
public
    property Quantity: Nullable<Integer> read FQuanitity write FQuanitity;
    property Description: Nullable<string> read FDescription write FDescription;
end;

FMyObectList: TObjectList<TMyObject>;
```

I would create a `TPrototypeBindSource` and bind FMyObjectList using the `OnCreateAdapeter`

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to do something like this?  Thanks

EDIT / Answer:

The best option for Nullable types is Spring4D, but there is no way to directly bind these values using Live bindings.

Comment: Delphi Spring4D has a good nullable type

Comment: Take a look at http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/09/18/38869

Comment: I'm actually using the spring nullable type in my test code.  The problem is when is bind my TNullableString property to a TListBox, the captions all come up blank.   If I switch back to string, the list shows fine.  Do i need to use a Custom Format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you register the type conversion for `Nullable<string>` to `string` and vice versa in the LiveBindings engine:

```
procedure RegisterNullableConversions;
begin
  TValueRefConverterFactory.UnRegisterConversion(TypeInfo(Nullable<string>), TypeInfo(string));
  TValueRefConverterFactory.RegisterConversion(TypeInfo(Nullable<string>), TypeInfo(string),
    TConverterDescription.Create(
      procedure(const I: TValue; var O: TValue)
      begin
        if I.AsType<Nullable<string>>.HasValue then
          O := I.AsType<Nullable<string>>.Value
        else
          O := 'null';
      end,
      'NullableToString', 'NullableToString', EmptyStr, True, EmptyStr, nil)
  );
  TValueRefConverterFactory.UnRegisterConversion(TypeInfo(string), TypeInfo(Nullable<string>));
  TValueRefConverterFactory.RegisterConversion(TypeInfo(string), TypeInfo(Nullable<string>),
    TConverterDescription.Create(
      procedure(const I: TValue; var O: TValue)
      begin
        O := TValue.From<Nullable<string>>(I.AsString);
      end,
      'StringToNullable', 'StringToNullable', EmptyStr, True, EmptyStr, nil)
  );
end;
```